# Inner Join on the same table

Tags: sql, inner-join

I have 2 queries, the first:

```
Select Distinct App_Form_Name,Control_Name
From Application_Form_Controls_Management
where Control_Type = 'ASPxGridView'
Order By App_Form_Name, Control_Name
```

which will return(for example):

```
App_Form_Name | Control_Name
Form1         | ControlName1
Form1         | ControlName2
```

The 2nd:

```
Select Distinct App_Form_Name, Right_ID, App_Form_Function_ID
From Application_Form_Controls_Management
where Control_Type = 'ASPxGridView'
Order By App_Form_Name,Right_ID,App_Form_Function_ID
```

which will return(for example):

```
App_Form_Name | Right_ID | App_Form_Function_ID
Form1         | 1        | 1
Form1         | 1        | 2
Form1         | 1        | 3
Form1         | 2        | 1
Form1         | 2        | 1
Form1         | 2        | 1
```

What I want is the `Inner Join` query that will return me the following result:

```
App_Form_Name | Control_Name | Right_ID | App_Form_Function_ID
Form1         | ControlName1 | 1        | 1
Form1         | ControlName1 | 1        | 2
Form1         | ControlName1 | 1        | 3
Form1         | ControlName1 | 2        | 1
Form1         | ControlName1 | 2        | 2
Form1         | ControlName1 | 2        | 3
Form1         | ControlName2 | 1        | 1
Form1         | ControlName2 | 1        | 2
Form1         | ControlName2 | 1        | 3
Form1         | ControlName2 | 1        | 1
Form1         | ControlName2 | 1        | 2
Form1         | ControlName2 | 1        | 3
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use your queries as sub queries like below:

```
Select a.App_Form_Name,a.Control_Name, b.Right_ID, b.App_Form_Function_ID
From
   (
    Select Distinct App_Form_Name,Control_Name From Application_Form_Controls_Management where Control_Type='ASPxGridView' 
   ) a
Inner join (
              Select Distinct App_Form_Name,Right_ID,App_Form_Function_ID From 
              Application_Form_Controls_Management where Control_Type='ASPxGridView'
           ) b
on a.App_Form_Name = b.App_Form_Name
```

If you are using SQL Server, you can also benefit from `cte` structure like:

```
;with cte as (
   Select Distinct App_Form_Name,Control_Name From 
   Application_Form_Controls_Management where Control_Type='ASPxGridView' 
),
cte2 as (
   Select Distinct App_Form_Name,Right_ID,App_Form_Function_ID From 
                   Application_Form_Controls_Management where Control_Type='ASPxGridView'
)
select cte.App_Form_Name,cte.Control_Name, cte2.Right_ID, cte2.App_Form_Function_ID
from cte
inner join cte2 on cte.App_Form_Name = cte2.App_Form_Name
```

Comment: a and b are Alias?

Comment: Two more question please, the first: yes I'm using SQL Server Management Studio so can I also use the ```cte``` structure in a stored procedure? and the second is:  if i run the first query it will give me 233 rows and the 2nd will give me 1406 rows, so when I do an ```Inner Join``` shouldn't it return me 233*1407=327 598 rows? Because when I execute the solution you provided me it returned only 6887 rows

Comment: I edited my previous comment and added another question.

Comment: As it is not a Cartesian product, we can't expect 233*1406 rows in the output unless all the rows has the same App_Form_Name value.

Comment: Thank you very much sir.